# Use both anonymize_ip and optimize_id on Gtag.js

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, gtag.js

I have set up the anonimize_ip parameter because of GDPR compliance etc...
My question is:how can I also use the optimize_id parameter?

1) In the same config line:

```
gtag('config', 'UA-123456789-1', { 'optimize_id': 'GTM-1234567'}, { 'anonymize_ip': true });
```

2) In two different lines for the same config:

```
gtag('config', 'UA-123456789-1', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
gtag('config', 'UA-123456789-1', { 'optimize_id': 'GTM-1234567'});
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for:

```
gtag('config', 'UA-123456789-1', { 'optimize_id': 'GTM-1234567', 'anonymize_ip': true })
```

That's a Javascript [object](https://javascript.info/object) with two keys and values

Answer (score 0):

Optimize uses profiling cookies so it doesn't make much sense to anonymize analytics but to activate optimize.
If anonymizeIp is true optimize does not appear, if anonymizeIp is false (i.e. because the user has accepted marketing cookies) then it can be released optimize as suggested by AdrianEddy.

Comment: anonymize_ip is needed for GDPR compliance. 
optimize_id would be used for split-testing in Google Optimize.

Are you sure that they would be conflicting? 
While I agree that anonymize_ip limits the functionalities, it doesn't sound too interlinked for this scenario...

Comment: I don't mean that they come into conflict with each other but that optimize could also be considered in the GDPR, since referring a user to version A or B of the site means profiling the user.